# Can someone identify this coin for me please?

Tags: identification, numismatics

Can someone identify this coin for me please? I found it when going through my mothers belongings after she passed away.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a souvenir coin rather than currency (as there's no value inscribed on it).

Comment: @SteveBird Indeed. But even more curious is the Latin lettering employed. Condition and lack of Soviet imagery/symbols and both names seem to point to 1991/post-1991? (Though I wonder how they left out the first part of _Санкт_-Петербург?)

Comment: Regarding the ship, could this be the frigatte [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS_Mir)? (It's not one of the [rubel](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RR5220-0004R.png) [coins](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RR5117-0031R.gif) featuring the ship.)

Comment: @ccprog If a ship, why such a late one built in Danzig? Wouldn't the/a [Shtandart/Штандартъ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_frigate_Shtandart) be 'a better match'?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Mainly because the rigging matches exactly. The Shtandart has only 8 full sails against 14 on the Mir (not counting the jibs/staysails). Additionally, the Mir often appears internationally in regattas, which would explain the latin inscription.

Comment: correction: 7 main sails, one spritsail and one lateen on the Shtandart.

Comment: i did use a magnifying glass on the ship and it has MNR (MIR) engraved on it so it would have to be from 1987 + i looked everywhere and could not find it as a medal token or coin

Comment: would not MIR in Russian be MЙР ?